# PHP Always return "Incorrect Email or Password" user

Tags: php

PHP always return "Incorrect Email or Password".. 
even though the Email and Passwd are correct at the login area, 
could someone help me?

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $passwordHash);

$stmt->execute();

$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if (count($users) <= 0)
{
    echo "Incorrect Email or Password";
exit;
}

// pega o primeiro usuário
$user = $users[0];

session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['name'];

header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Comment: How is `$passwordHash` built? How was the password inserted into the DB?

Comment: I had create with $passwordHash = make_hash($password);

Comment: But now after you ask me about, I changed $stmt->bindParam(':password', $passwordHash); to $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);  and it's run ok now but if I want to run with the passwd "make_hash" how could I do it?..

Comment: What is `make_hash`? Is the password hashed in your DB or is it plaintext?

Comment: A quick note makes sure the characters length is enough when inserting into a database or else only partial data will be inserted. This happened to me once.